# Calling a function for every dictionary in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

As input I have a list of dictionaries like the example below

```
list = [
         {"name": "John", "age": 36, "gender": "Male"},
         {"name": "Lisa", "age": 40, "gender": "Female"},
         {"name": "Mary", "age": 26, "gender": "Female"},
          ...
       ]
```

I want to run a function where I use the values in the dictionary as arguments, and for every dictionary in the list

```
def value(person_name, person_age, person_gender):
    "returns a value based on arguments"
```

As output I need to return a list of the values calculated by the function for every dictionary. For example:

```
[def value(John, 36, Male), def value(Lisa, 40, Female), def value(Mary, 26, Female), ...]
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please share your attempt with us, and also share what the output is supposed to look like based on your input?

Comment: You left out the most important part.. the function. Can you include some dummy function if it's too long to share? As well as expected output.

Comment: You can do this easily with either `map` or a list comprehension. Try looking those up if you're not familiar with them.

Comment: Surely you'll manage to write a loop and call a function with 3 values from a dictionary? Not really sure what the problem here is.

Comment: are you trying to literally return the dictionary's values as a list? If so, why not use the `values()` method of the `dict` object? You don't need a function for this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list comprehension.

```
result = [values(p['name'], p['age'], p['gender']) for p in list]
```

Answer (score 1):

kwargs should be useful here, note though that the names of the function parameters need to exactly match the keys of the dictionaries in order to use this

```
list = [
         {"name": "John", "age": 36, "gender": "Male"},
         {"name": "Lisa", "age": 40, "gender": "Female"},
         {"name": "Mary", "age": 26, "gender": "Female"},
       ]

def func1(name, age, gender):
    print("1: ", name)

def func2(name, age, gender):
    print("2: ", name)

def func3(name, age, gender):
    print("3: ", name)

for d in list:
    func1(**d)
    func2(**d)
    func3(**d)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you name your function parameters the same as the keys of `dict`, you can simply unpack them with `**` same as below example:

```
data = [
         {"name": "John", "age": 36, "gender": "Male"},
         {"name": "Lisa", "age": 40, "gender": "Female"},
         {"name": "Mary", "age": 26, "gender": "Female"}
       ]

def value(name, age, gender):
    return 'Name: {},  Age: {}, Gender: {}.'.format(name, age, gender)

[value(**i) for i in data]
#['Name: John,  Age: 36, Gender: Male.',
# 'Name: Lisa,  Age: 40, Gender: Female.',
# 'Name: Mary,  Age: 26, Gender: Female.']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could send the entire dictionary and unpack it in the function

```
def value(x):
    name = x['name']
    age = x['age']
    gender = x['gender']
    # do something
    # return something 

for i in lista:            # full loop
    value(i)

[value(i) for i in lista]  # list comprehension
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple case of `map`:

```
data = [
     {"name": "John", "age": 36, "gender": "Male"},
     {"name": "Lisa", "age": 40, "gender": "Female"},
     {"name": "Mary", "age": 26, "gender": "Female"},
      ...
   ]

def value(**kwargs):
    ...

result = list(map(data, value))
```